# getElementsBySelector failing in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I am dealing with Internet Explorer 8, I have the following code:

```
this.scrolling  = false;
    this.wrapper    = $(wrapper);
    //this.scroller = this.wrapper.down('div.elscroller');
    if (this.wrapper.querySelectorAll('div.elscroller') != null ) {
        this.scroller   = this.wrapper.querySelectorAll('div.elscroller');
    }
    this.sections   = this.wrapper.getElementsBySelector('div.seccion');
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE throws: Object doesn't support this property or method in this line: `this.sections   = this.wrapper.getElementsBySelector('div.seccion');`

the HTML code, is like this:

```
<div class="elscroller">
  <div class="seccion" id="seccion1"></div>
  <div class="seccion" id="seccion..n"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a line commented, because it had the same problem, so I went into a primitive way of doing stuff, and put an if there. Only God knows how, but it has worked.

I am really tired of coding especially for IE8. I hope some day people stop using this #%! browser.

Comment: What returns `$.toSring();` ?

Comment: @plalx it returns: **Error: Object doesn't support this property or method** and stops parsing

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PrototypeJS then you can do it this way which will work across all browsers

```
this.sections   = this.wrapper.select('div.seccion');
```

`this.sections` will be an array of DOM elements matching the CSS selector `div.seccion`

Comment: This throws: Object doesn't support this property or method. I simply do not know what happens with this browser

Comment: `select()` is a PrototypeJS method - are you sure you are loading the prototype framework? Are you loading the latest version (1.7.2 April 2014).